# Retrive only X records from PySpark GroupBy / OrderBy without aggregation

Tags: python, pyspark, window

Assume I have a dataset like this (way bigger ofc):

| Product | Serial | Feature 1 | Feature 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 123 | 1.1 | 2.2 |
| 1234 | 123 | 1.3 | 2.3 |
| 5678 | 456 | 1.4 | 2.4 |
| 5678 | 456 | 1.5 | 2.5 |
| 9111 | 567 | 1.6 | 2.6 |
| 1234 | 124 | 1.7 | 2.7 |

Consider the product as a type of product and serial as the identification number of a specific part. I would like to sort values by "Product" and "Serial" and also group data by the same columns ("Product" and "Serial"). After that I want to iterate over those groups so that I can, for example, grab data belonging to the groups 2-4. In pandas I implemented this by:

```
ds = dataset.reset_index(drop=True)
ds.sort_values(by=['Product','Serial'], inplace=True)
ds = ds.groupby(['Product','Serial'])

#Add index to a list for later

listDF = []
dsSize = 0

for key,item in ds:
    listDF.append(key)
    dsSize = dsSize +1
print("Group Size: ", dsSize)
```

Later i would simply iterate over this index list and get the groups I wanted.

```
for i in trainInterval:
    sTrain.append(ds.get_group(listDF[i]))

#Create new datasets
train = pd.DataFrame()
train = train.append([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in sTrain], ignore_index = True)
```

Where trainInterval is a range that I change according to my needs.
For scalability purposes I'm trying to convert all my code to PySpark and I'm having some troubles with the basic functions although I already went through RDD Programming Guide. So far I've tried two methods but I'm stuck in the same stage for both:

1:

```
ds.orderBy(col("Product"),col("Serial"))
ds = screwingProfile.groupBy(col("Product"),col("Serial"))
```

I don't know where to go from here as it seems iterating over a DataGroup object is not possible (I'm probably doing something wrong).

2:

```
w1 = Window.partitionBy('Product','Serial').orderBy('Product','Serial')
```

I don't know what to do next. Most solutions I see online do some math over the columns and I just want them to be grouped as indicated so I can then compose a dataframe to send to my Machine Learning Algorithms. After getting this groups can I just append them together (with union?)?

**EDIT**:
For clarification purposes this table illustrates the "grouped" df. I have a product with multiple serials and a serial has multiple records.

```
+-------+------+--------+--------+
|Product|Serial|Feature1|Feature2|
+-------+------+--------+--------+
|   1234|   123|     1.1|     2.2|
|       |      |     1.3|     2.4|
|       |      |     1.7|     2.7|
|       |      |     3  |     2.8|
|       |      |     2  |     2.9|
|       |      |     1.4|     2.4|
|       |   124|     1.7|     2.6|
|       |      |     1.2|     2.4|
|       |      |     1.9|     2.2|
|       |      |    3 .1|     2.3|
|       |      |     2  |     2.4|
|       |      |     1.9|     2.4|
|  ...  |  ... |   ...  |   ...  |
|  ...  |  ... |   ...  |   ...  |
|  ...  |  ... |   ...  |   ...  |
+-------+------+--------+--------+
```

**Edit 2:**

I was able to proceed on my quest by using this code:

```py
    w = Window.partitionBy('product').orderBy(F.asc('serial'))
    x = screwingProfile.withColumn("rank",rank().over(w)) \
        .orderBy(column_list)
```

And now I get this output:

```
+--------+-------+-------+--------+----+
| Product| Serial|Featur1|Featur2 |rank|
+--------+-------+-------+--------+----+
|    A   |  123  |    1.1|     9.1|   1|
|    A   |  123  |    2.1|       1|   1|
|    A   |  123  |    1.1|     9.2|   1|
|    A   |  456  |    3.1|     7.3|4112|
```

It's super close to what I want but for the "second group" i was expecting the rank to be 2 instead of 4112. Maybe i shouldn't be using rank and use anything else? I tried 'monotonically_increasing_id()' but its not supported within a window function. Also tried dense_rank which at first looks like it accomplished what I want but then , on the next serial , say 789 its rank values is 1 again instead of 3.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use [`row_number`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number) would give you the correct order